# How to get the variable values with same prefix in a single command in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have few env variables like

```
variable_a=xxx
variable_b=yyy
variable_c=zzz
```

I want to set all these to another variable. How can I do this with single command with referring to the prefix *variable_*
I know, we can do this something like `new_var=${variable_a} ${variable_b} ${variable_c}`.
But I need to know whether we can do this with prefix referencing.

Comment: `with prefix referencing` What is this "prefix referencing"? There is no such thing [in bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a special `${!var*}` expansion in bash to get the list of set variable names. Then you can iterate over them and use indirect expansion to get the value. And then join the values with spaces.

```
new_var=$(
      for i in ${!variable_*}; do
          printf "%s\n" "${!i}"
      done | paste -sd ' '
)
```